# Remove last name but keep initial

Tags: php

I cannot show last names on my reviews due to hipaa laws, so I'm trying to keep the first name and only show the initial of the last name.

**For example:**
Carole Baskin left a 5 Star Review on Google...

**I would need it to say:**
Carole B left a 5 Star Review on Google.

**Here is my xml structure if needed:**

```
<item>
<title>Carole Baskin left a 5 Star Review on Google</title>
<description>Maecenas ullamcorper id eros nec dictum. Proin mattis ullamcorper nisl, id gravida tortor eleifend at. Fusce condimentum mauris non iaculis eleifend.</description>
</item>
```

Would I used the `trim` function for something like this?

**Here is my PHP code:**

```
$arr = array();
$xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml') or die('Failed to create an object');
  foreach($xml->channel->children() as $xml_node) {     
    $arr = array($xml_node->title, $xml_node->description);
}
```

I'm sure this could be done because there is a space after the first name (Carole). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show your php code as well

Comment: @Chilarai done :)

Comment: Are all items in the form of "firstname lastname"? What if "Ian Lancaster Fleming" or "Dr. Indiana Jones" left a review?

Comment: @kerbh0lz yes! All are in the form of first name last name. Sorry, i've should of mentioned that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. Check this

```
    $arr = array();
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('data.xml') or die('Failed to create an object');
      foreach($xml->channel->children() as $xml_node) {     
        
    
        $titleArray = explode(" ", $xml_node->title);
        $firstname = $titleArray[0];
        $lastname = $titleArray[1];
        $rating = $titleArray[4];
    
        $lastnameFirstChar = $lastname[0];
        $name =  $firstname ." ".$lastnameFirstChar ;
    
        $titleFinal =  sprintf("%s left a %s Star Review on Google", $name, $rating);

        $arr = array($titleFinal, $xml_node->description);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $name = "Carole Baskin";
    $namesArr = explode(" ", $name);
    $nameStr = $namesArr[0];
    if (!empty($namesArr[1])) {
        $nameStr .= substr($namesArr[1], 0, 1);
    }
    $rating = 5;

    echo $reviewTitle = sprintf("%s left a %s Star Review on Google", $nameStr, $rating);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Really appreciate it!