# Remove last name but keep initial with XSLT

Tags: php, xslt

I created a post a few days ago - which you can find here [Remove last name but keep initial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067663/remove-last-name-but-keep-initial/63067928#63067928). I got the answer I needed for PHP but now I need to figure out how to do the same exact thing with xslt template.

I cannot show last names on my reviews due to hipaa laws, so I'm trying to keep the first name and only show the initial of the last name.

**Here is my xml structure if needed (data.xml):**

```
<item>
<title>Carole Baskin left a 5 Star Review on Google</title>
<description>Maecenas ullamcorper id eros nec dictum. Proin mattis ullamcorper nisl, id gravida tortor eleifend at. Fusce condimentum mauris non iaculis eleifend.</description>
</item>
```

**Here is my xsl template code below (xsl.xml).** The select="title" would display the first and last name. For example: Carole Baskin left a 5 Star Review on Google. I need it to say "Carole B left a 5 Star Review on Google"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="php"
    version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="/rss/channel">
    <xsl:for-each select="item[description[normalize-space() and php:function('str_word_count', string()) &lt; 50]]">
    
    <li>
        <p style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border-radius: 25px; padding:22px;" class="heading">
            <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </p>

        <p class="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </p>
    </li>
    
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP code I'm using to load in the xsl:**

```
<?php
   $xmlFile = "data.xml;
   $xslFile = "xsl.xml";
                        
   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   $xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
                    
   $doc->load($xslFile);
   $xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
   $xsl->registerPHPFunctions();
    
   $xsl->importStyleSheet($doc);
                    
   $doc->load($xmlFile);
   echo $xsl->transformToXML($doc);
?>
```

Comment: For XSLT questions you need to say which version of XSLT you are using, since this will very often affect the answer. This is especially true for questions involving string manipulation, which in XSLT 2.0+ can be done using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as you say in a comment to your other question) the last name is always the string between the 1st and 2nd space of `title`, you can replace:

```
<xsl:value-of select="title"/>
```

with:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(title, ' ')"/>
<xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after(title, ' ')"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring($tail, 1, 1)"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after($tail, ' ')"/>
```

or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:variable name="head" select="substring-before(title, ' ')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="substring(title, 1, string-length($head) + 2)"/>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after(title, ' '), ' ')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was trying to do :)